# Terraform kubernetes deployment with pod readinessgates

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

We use terraform resource "kubernetes_deployment" to deploy our pods.
Our pods have readiness probes, but these probes are not good enough because we need external feedback to decide if a pod is ready. In our case, a pod is ready only after external program creates a file in aws S3 bucket, and this is a manual step, which may be completed at random time (can be several days/weeks)  so readiness probe is not good, becuase it will fail and leave our pod in "unready" state.
We understand kubernetes 1.14 introduced something called readiness-gate. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-readiness-gate
However it seems terraform resource "kubernetes_deployment" does not support pod readiness-gates.

Note that we prefer using kubernetes deployment (rather than defining pods directly) because we need rolling update strategy.

How can we define pod readiness-gates with terraform?

Comment: i opened a feature request for this on terreform-kubernetes github repo:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you cannot define pod readiness-gates with terraform.

You can create a feature request on [terreform-kubernetes github repo](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues) or add this functionality by yourself and create a pull request.

For now you can use initContainers (as already mentioned by Yuri) 
or use readiness probe with command that uses bash to string together check for an application readiness and existence of a file.

But probably the best thing you could do is to rewrite your application, so it can handle the case when file doesn't exist yet.

Comment: readiness probe with command that uses bash to "string together" check for an application readiness and existence of a file will not work for us because when the file does not exist then readiness probe will fail repeatedly and pod will be moved to "unready" state. In such case we will have no way to move it back to "ready" state when the file is eventually created

Comment: i cannot rewrite the application, so it can handle the case when file doesn't exist yet because but this file is a "application policy" file, without it the application does not know how to process requests. 
I can change the readiness probe to return http status code 200 if file exists and http status code 250 (any value from 200 to 399 is considered successful by kubernetes) if the file does not exist. However this approach puts extra burden on the application client which will need to check the http status code and retry if it gets code 250. Seems like a bad approach,

Comment: "In such case we will have no way to move it back to "ready" state when the file is eventually created" - why do you think so? As soon as file gets created, readines probe should stop failing and pod state should be changed to "ready".

Comment: i was under the impression that after readiness fails number of "failureThreshold" times, it gives up and NEVER tries again. But following your remark i read the documentation again and it seems you are right, the readiness probe continues to try after failing, and will eventually succeed once the file exist :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use initcontainer to check the status of S3 bucket. I sent you an example below:

’’
initContainers:
  - name: install
    image: busybox
    command:
    - wget
    - "-O"
    - "/work-dir/index.html"
    - http://kubernetes.io
’’

Comment: thanks for the initcontainer example. initcontainer means an extra container and extra resources (mem/cpu). It also introduces another point of failure. So we are hesitant to take this approach